# When using Google Sites with a Godaddy domain, how do you alias example.com to www.example.com?

Tags: 301-redirect, godaddy, google-workspace, no-www

I know how to do this in an Apache2 config file and my own DNS configuration... But here I'm forced to host the site at Google Apps and the DNS at `Goddady.com`. What's the easiest way to alias `example.com` to `www.example.com` in this situation? I'm sure I need a forwarding mechanism. Without introducing an intermediary Apache server just for this purpose, if at all possible..

Answer (score 1):

Sign into your Google Apps Dashboard, go to `Domain Settings` -> `Domain Names`, from there you have the option to setup your naked domain redirection - follow the instructions presented, you will need to set up a new `'A'` record (this is one of the very rare cases in Google Apps setup which doesn't use a `'CNAME'` record).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of aliasing www.example.com to example.com, you should configure example.com as Google points out, then create a CNAME in your Godaddy DNS configuration that points to example.com.

You can find more details on configuring CNAMES with Godaddy [here](http://help.godaddy.com/article/680#cnames).

Answer (score 0):

. names or example.com can't use CNAMES,you have use an A address. If you do nslookup on ghs.google.com, it shows 3-4 IP addresses, pick any and add this as A record for example.com. It will work, with only issue being if that IP is down or changes, example.com would go down.